# How to get annotation parameter in annotation processor

Tags: java, kotlin, annotations, annotation-processing

I'm writing my own annotation processor and I'm trying to get parameter of my annotation like in the code below in process method:

```
roundEnv.getElementsAnnotatedWith(annotation).forEach {
        val annotation = it.getAnnotation(annotation)
        annotation.interfaces
}
```

What I get is `An exception occurred: javax.lang.model.type.MirroredTypesException: Attempt to access Class objects for TypeMirrors []` during build. Anyone know how to get annotation data?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The documentation on the `getAnnotation` method explains why `Class<?>` objects are problematic for an annotation processor:

> The annotation returned by this method could contain an element whose value is of type Class. This value cannot be returned directly: information necessary to locate and load a class (such as the class loader to use) is not available, and the class might not be loadable at all. Attempting to read a Class object by invoking the relevant method on the returned annotation will result in a MirroredTypeException, from which the corresponding TypeMirror may be extracted. Similarly, attempting to read a Class[]-valued element will result in a MirroredTypesException.

To access annotation elements like classes you need to instead use `Element.getAnnotationMirrors()` and manually find the annotation of interest. These annotation mirrors will contain elements representing the actual values but without requiring the presence of the classes in question.

Answer (score 0):

This [blog post](https://area-51.blog/2009/02/13/getting-class-values-from-annotations-in-an-annotationprocessor/) seems to be the canonical source for how to do this. It references a Sun forum discussion and is referenced in a number of annotation processors.

For the following annotation:

```
@Documented
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
public @interface Action {
    Class<?> value();
}
```

The field of type `Class<?>` can be accessed through this code:

```
for (ExecutableElement ee : ElementFilter.methodsIn(te.getEnclosedElements())) {
    Action action = ee.getAnnotation(Action.class);
    if (action == null) {
        // Look for the overridden method
        ExecutableElement oe = getExecutableElement(te, ee.getSimpleName());
        if (oe != null) {
            action = oe.getAnnotation(Action.class);
        }
    }

    TypeMirror value = null;
    if (action != null) {
        try {
            action.value();
        } catch (MirroredTypeException mte) {
            value = mte.getTypeMirror();
        }
    }

    System.out.printf(“ % s Action value = %s\n”,ee.getSimpleName(), value);
}
```